# How do you configure Windows firewall for selective web browsing?

Tags: security, windows-server-2019, windows-firewall

I'm configuring administrative hosts in a management subnet. I've installed Chromium to enable our technology staff to be able to browse to our internal web management interfaces for administrative tasks, but I want to block them browsing the internet. I can't block the hosts themselves from the internet because they have other processes which need to communicate with cloud services, etc., so I planned to just restrict the Chromium executable by destination subnet, ACL-style.

I tried to use the Windows firewall to achieve this:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -Direction Outbound -DisplayName 'Block Chromium from Internet' `
-Group 'Jumpbox Security' -Enabled True -Profile Any `
-Program 'C:\Program Files\Chromium\Application\chrome.exe' -Protocol TCP -Action Block `
-RemoteAddress 0.0.0.0/0

New-NetFirewallRule -Direction Outbound -DisplayName 'Allow Chromium to Internal Networks' `
-Group 'Jumpbox Security' -Enabled True -Profile Any `
-Program 'C:\Program Files\Chromium\Application\chrome.exe' -Protocol TCP -Action Allow `
-RemoteAddress 10.0.0.0/8 -OverrideBlockRules Allow
```

I tried this on both the outbound and inbound rule sets and it does not restrict Chromium at all, presumably because the first rule is being invalidated by another rule match. Before I begin a tedious rule audit and apply additional, more complicated configuration, does anyone know of a cleaner way to achieve the end result?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a whitelist. Start by blocking all access and then document what you need the users to have access to and allow only those.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but is that not exactly what I did? My first rule attempted block Chromium from 0.0.0.0/0 (which is everything), and in the second I tried to override that by whitelisting the internal subnets.

Or do you have a means to configure this other than the local firewall?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the rules are applied top down? Most firewalls apply the top most rule first.

Comment: Yes, the Windows firewall does not process in a rule-by-rule order. It takes the broadest match in this general order: block, allow, default. Since my test configuration allows Chromium to browse unrestricted, I've been parsing the rules to see what it could be matching. So far no luck.

Comment: Do you have a separate firewall further upstream?

Comment: Yes, but not one that could tell the difference between a browser and any other internet traffic. I gave up on using the firewall for this, swapped Chrome for Chromium, and configured a GPO to leverage Chrome's URL allowed settings.

Comment: Why not put the whitelist there?